# Make the second column of a table span on the first one if too long

Tags: html, css, html-table

So basically here is my current result:

```
24 February   TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE
              TITLE TITLE
              CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
```

And I want this instead:

```
24 February   TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE
TITLE TITLE
              CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11 February</td>
    <td>TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE</td>
  </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
}


td:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

I have no idea how to achieve what I want or even if it's a good idea to use HTML tables, so I'm open to any suggestion!

Comment: Why you want use `table` ?

Comment: It's the only solution I thought of, but I'm open to use anything else. I tried simple `<p>` and a float left but it didn't work out, or even inline-blocks but again no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is?

```css
.a {
  width:50%;
}

.aa {
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
}

.ab {
   display:inline;
   word-break:break-word;
}

.b {
  word-break:break-word;
  margin-left:125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="aa">
  24 February 
  </div>
  <div class="ab">
    TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for, `word-break` was the piece I was missing.